# Trouble making files in Windows folder lowercase

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to make all files in a Windows 10 folder lowercase

I ran the following command but some of the files still have uppercase letters for some reason

```
for /f "Tokens=*" %f in ('dir /l/b/a-d') do (rename "%f" "%f")
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Weird. That command should work ... it does on Window 7. Do you have the correct permissions on the files that still have uppercase letters?

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell and check that your $files var contains all of the files

```
#Append -recurse if you want to go recursively, you can also adjust the filter - it gets a list of File objects that match the criteria you set
$files = gci 'C:\WhateverDirectory' -filter '*.*' -File
#This loops through all of the files in $files and renames them.
$files | % {Rename-Item $_ -newname $_.Name.ToLower()}
```